# How do I set up lighttpd for x.509 client certificate authentication

Tags: ssl, http, lighttpd, certificate

So far I've had HTTPS working for a long time, so I don't think there are any trouble with the server certificates. Now I tried to add this to lighttpd.conf:

```
ssl.engine                  = "enable"
ssl.cipher-list = "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:RC4-SHA:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH:!AESGCM"
ssl.pemfile                 = "/etc/ssl/private/steinbitglis.domain.pem"
ssl.ca-file                 = "/etc/ssl/private/GandiStandardSSLCA.pem"
ssl.verifyclient.activate   = "enable"
ssl.verifyclient.enforce    = "enable"
```

The lighttpd error log says this:

```
(connections.c.299) SSL: 1 error:140890C7:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE:peer did not return a certificate
```

Firefox claims the following:

```
ssl_error_handshake_failure_alert
```

My goal is to replace username+passphrase with browser certificates, but I've not even been able to request any certificate from the browser yet. If anyone knows a good source to learn all the details I need to play with this technology, that would be awesome.

This is a test I did from a remote machine.

```
$ openssl s_client -CAfile GandiStandardSSLCA.pem -showcerts -connect steinbitglis.domain:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, ST = UT, L = Salt Lake City, O = The USERTRUST Network, OU = http://www.usertrust.com, CN = UTN-USERFirst-Hardware
verify return:1
depth=1 C = FR, O = GANDI SAS, CN = Gandi Standard SSL CA
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = Gandi Standard SSL, CN = steinbitglis.domain
verify return:1
139713412519584:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1195:SSL alert number 40
139713412519584:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:591:
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Gandi Standard SSL/CN=steinbitglis.domain
   i:/C=FR/O=GANDI SAS/CN=Gandi Standard SSL CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=FR/O=GANDI SAS/CN=Gandi Standard SSL CA
   i:/C=US/ST=UT/L=Salt Lake City/O=The USERTRUST Network/OU=http://www.usertrust.com/CN=UTN-USERFirst-Hardware
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Gandi Standard SSL/CN=steinbitglis.domain
issuer=/C=FR/O=GANDI SAS/CN=Gandi Standard SSL CA
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/C=FR/O=GANDI SAS/CN=Gandi Standard SSL CA
---
SSL handshake has read 2657 bytes and written 347 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : SSLv3
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: CFD6D9A88B96888E9114F1EFF5DD23C83082D24F571B30105BA793FD06A1C311
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 4106EE7BB7FF8DE9793431CFFD4175842D02C08AC055D315DBEF7B9BCAD3FF5032769A18775142BEA2AF9E80694A32B3
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1338161044
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `openssl s_client -showcerts -CApath /etc/ssl/certs -connect myserver:443`?

Comment: It was too long to post as a comment, so I added it to the question. The three lines following "CONNECTED" came to stderr.

Comment: Editing the question is the correct thing to do when adding information. `No client certificate CA names sent`: this means that Lighttpd is not telling the client which CAs are valid for client certificates, which usually means that the client won't send a certificate. I can't seem to find the configuration to do this though...

Answer (score 3):

```
No client certificate CA names sent
```

This means that Lighttpd is not telling the client which CAs are valid for client certificates. This usually means that the client will not send a client certificate (since it is not able to decide which certificate to use).

It isn't very clear, but [#1288](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/1288) implies that the [`ssl.ca-file`](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:SSL#Configuration) directive is used to specify the trusted CAs for client authentication, and I would think that this would be used to send the list of acceptable CAs to the client. Make sure that your `ca-file` includes the CA which your client certificate is signed by.

Comment: I added some info about that config.
ssl.ca-file                 = "/etc/ssl/private/GandiStandardSSLCA.pem"

Comment: Ok, I think I got my own environment trouble out of the way. Now I have some more realistic output from `openssl` in my question.

Comment: Good, Lighttpd is sending acceptable CA names now. Is your client's certificate signed by `/C=FR/O=GANDI SAS/CN=Gandi Standard SSL CA`? If not, append the CA certificate for client certificates to the `ssl.ca-file`.

Comment: Tried again with `-CAfile GandiStandardSSLCA.pem`. Update in my question.

Comment: @Steinbitglis I'm referring to the `ssl.ca-file` set in Lighttpd, not the `s_client` test. Is the CA which the client certificates are signed by included in the `ssl.ca-file` configured in Lighttpd?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the client browser has no certificate to provide yet. I thought that the server should request this to be created? I'm guessing I have to selectively turn off `ssl.verifyclient.enforce = "enable"` to be able to make that request? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: I don't know of any mechanism where a webserver can request the client to generate a certificate (and I don't think you want this, since the whole point of this is to provide authentication). I think there may be a JavaScript API to generate certificates, but you'd still need to implement uploading and trusting the certificate. Your best path is to generate and sign the client certificates out of band.

Comment: This video demonstrates what I thought I would be doing. Probably I'll have to find some source of info about this technique. I also want to do WebID, but first: certificates.
http://vimeo.com/14798335